# How to find pinned folders in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer

I have a few folders pinned in File Explorer in Windows 8.1, but cannot get them unpinned for some reason. When I try to unpin nothing happens. Other folders can be unpinned. Where can I find this on my PC in either the registry or in appdata? Thanks!

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean when you say you have files "pinned in File Explorer"?  Where exactly do you have them pinned?  I'm confused because you can pin stuff to the Start Screen, or the Task Bar, but not "in Explorer".

Answer (score 1):

The pinned file are seen in `Start` window. Just move the cursor to left bottom corner and move your mouse to right where you can see what folder, files, app you pin previously. Right click on app for unpin from  `Start` menu a popup will be shown on bottom of window and click on `Unpin from Start`.